# Bash completion for `unset` command

Tags: bash, autocomplete

How can I setup bash completion for the `unset` command, like when you use `echo $XXX`, you can get a completion for `XXX`?

Comment: It seems to work already.

Comment: @enzotib really ? i tried `unset TM<tab>` and nothing appears , but `unset $TM<tab>` , which is not the case ...

Comment: It probably works already with the bash completion package from http://www.caliban.org/bash/#completion_download installed. (On Fedora or with EPEL, `yum install bash-completion`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to turn on bash's programmable completion system. There's a file called `bash_completion` distributed with bash that you must include from your `.bashrc`. On typical distributions, put this in `~/.bashrc`:

```
. /etc/bash.completion
```

If this file is not present on your system, it may be in a separate package from the main bash executable, e.g. `bash-completion` on Debian.

If you specifically want completion for the `unset` command, that's

```
complete -v unset
```

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu/Bash system:

```
TM1=A; TM2=B
unset TM<ESC><*>
 => unset TM1 TM2  (expands in the command line)
```